# How does BitTorrent seed files on a shared IP?

Tags: ip, bittorrent

I am reading about BitTorrent, and the one thing I do not understand is that when I am on a shared IP, how does it seed files to others?

How do the others connect to my computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "shared IP"? Do you mean your ISP has supplied you with a public IP that you "share" with other people connected to the same DLSAM, or a local IP you share with other users on the same LAN? If the former, the DSLAM you're connected to has a NAT functionality, if only to bill you for any extra you might consume (toll phone numbers, off-limit bandwidth usage, etc...), so that's how the files you seed will be found by trackers, and other users will be able to download them from your computer.

Comment: I meant "DSLAM" (digital subscriber line access multiplexer) of course... :-/

Comment: @Didier
Thanks, I meant the first case. I have a public IP that I share with other people. Would you please provide a link for further reading on the DSLAM thing? for example, Can I run my webserver like this and will it be discoverable by other people?

Comment: I don't have any link handy as to how it would work for you, (except this one about what a DSLAM is and what it does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer), but lotsa businesses rely on shared public IP addresses for their business because their websites are hosted on server farms, and they usually share their server with other users. You can create a website, buy a domain name, and host it at home; once it's online (as in, published), search engines will index it for sure. May not show on 1st first page of results, though. Search "SEO" in Google for that...

Comment: My problem is about the "host it at home" part, I don't know if it will be OK with a domain or not. But by running a webserver and setting up NAT on my router, I still cannot access it on the internet (using my public IP)

Comment: Have you tried to bridge your router connection to your PC instead of NAT? Just for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, even the router's remote Administration does not work outside of LAN when enabled.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps you've undergone to forward port(s) from your router to your PC where the web server is? What's the operating system on the PC/server? If it's Windows, have you enabled IIS (like this: https://quehow.com/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-10/4155.html)?